# Can I reduce size of array in CUDA

Tags: memory-management, cuda, gpu, nvidia, allocation

I have allocated memory for 3d array using cudaMalloc3D - after execution of first kernel I established that I do not need part of it.
For example in pseudo code :

```
A = [100,100,100]
kernel()// data of intrest is just in subrange of A
B = [10:20, 20:100, 50:80]// part that I need other entries I would like to have removed
... // new allocations
kernelb()...
```

The rest of memory I would like to free (or immidiately use to other arrays  that I will need to allocate now)

I know that I can free array and reallocate - but It do not seem to the best option.
P.S.

By the way Is there a way to use cudaMallocAsync like cudaMalloc3D - I mean cudaMalloc3D makes it convienient to use 3d array and takes care for paddings.

Comment: What is your question? Would you like to know how to embed a multi-dimension array into a linear array? Would you like to know if  there is `realloc` for CUDA?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out yes I would like to know is there realloc for array allocated with cudaMalloc3D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current CUDA API does not have realloc functionality.
It seems you already know the common workaround of `cudaMalloc smaller array -> cudaMemcpy to smaller array -> cudaFree large array`

In case you really need `realloc`, you could write your own allocator using GPU virtual memory management. https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/introducing-low-level-gpu-virtual-memory-management/